# $this->htmlEscape is not working in custom theme Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, theme

Custom developed Magento 1.x theme `$this->htmlEscape` function is not working though it's working on `frontend/base/default` theme.

Please suggest what cause it happening?

Thanks in advanced.

---

Edit (from deleted answer comments):

> @sv3v, yeah solved the problem. There was another error in the theme
>   that was not related with $this->htmlEscape. I guessed wrong BTW
>   thanks for your time and support.